# How can I find out what is causing the delay on my Enter key?

Tags: vim, neovim

I'm new to Vim and I'm generally loving how responsive it is. Where it is not responsive, though, is in pressing my `<Enter>` key during Insert mode. When I hit it I get a half-second (feels like centuries) pause before the cursor actually shifts down. I suspect that it's waiting for a subsequent key, because if I set `timeoutlen`to 0 then it's not a problem. Is there any way I can eliminate this unwanted opportunity to rest & recuperate? I've looked at :map but it's not obvious what might be causing it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had the right idea, except you want to look at `:imap`, not `:map`, to see the mappings that are enabled in insert mode.

Comment: Thanks. I got the suspect. I remapped <CR><Space> for some plugin that I got carried away installing and which never worked and which I never really needed to begin with.